# Custom progress Bar on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

How do I create a custom progress bar on iOS?

Comment: You need to tell us what you tried and post some code. This is not a request forum.

Comment: here is a progress bar on Forrst might give you a basis on which you vcan edit/add to [progress bar post](http://forrst.com/posts/HUD_Progress_bar_written_in_Objective_C_for_iPho-mKZ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have 2 images, the "on" image is on top of the "off" image, and each in their own UIImageView. Enable `clipsToBound` for the UIImageView containing "on" image. Then you can adjust the width of the bounds for the top image according to the number that controls it. You can also choose to make the change continuous or discreet.

Answer (score 1):

You did not post the image :) But you can use UISlider with "userInteractionEnabled" set to NO and thumb set to small, transparent image. Here's some code:

```
UIImage* slider = [UIImage imageNamed:@"empty.png"];
UIImage* leftImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"left_track.png"];
UIImage* rightImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"right_track.png"];

[self.slider setThumbImage::slider forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.slider setThumbImage::slider forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[self.slider setThumbImage::slider forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[self.slider setMinimumTrackImage::leftImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.slider setMaximumTrackImage::rightImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Ofcourse, images left and right must be scalable.